# Route Waypoints line it is not shown correctly when map is finished

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap, geojson

I am adding in the map waypoints like in the image below. In most cases, the points and the line between points it is showing correctly but in one case when the point is in the finish of the map it is happening a problem the line doesn't follow the points but it is going in the last point ignoring the other points. Please check the images.

- [maproute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srHRP.png)
- [ma2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDjZH.png)
- [workingcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iNM6.png)

```
easyFetch(url,
        function(data){
         var obj = JSON.parse(data);
         geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
          styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
          "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
          pointRadius: 2,
          fillColor: "red",
          fillOpacity: 1,
          strokeColor: "black",
          strokeWidth: 0.1,
          strokeOpacity: 1 } ),
          "select": { fillColor: "#8aeeef",
          strokeColor: "#32a8a9",
          labelYOffset:13,
          label:"${name}"}

          //Text entspricht feature.attributes.name
        }),
        //projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        //strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        //protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
         // url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1gw97c',
          //url:'https://api.myjson.com/bins/sqri8',
          //format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
        // })
        }),

          map.addLayer(geojson_layer); 
        //setTimeout(function() {
        //var points = [];
        //geojson_layer.features.forEach(function(feature) { points.push(feature.geometry); });
        //geojson_layer.addFeatures([
           //new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points), {}, {})
        //]);
        //}, 5000);
        var features = [];
        var points = [];
        obj.Waypoints.forEach(function(wp) {
        var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(wp.Lon, wp.Lat).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        map.getProjectionObject()
        );
        features.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point));
        points.push(point);
        })
        features.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points), {}, {}));
        geojson_layer.addFeatures(features);

            //console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
            //alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
            //console.log("TotalDistance:" + JSON.stringify(obj.TotalDistance));
            //alert("TotalDistance:" + JSON.stringify(obj.TotalDistance));
            document.getElementById('dist').innerHTML = ("TotalDistance:" + JSON.stringify(obj.TotalDistance));
            document.getElementById('TotalDistance').innerHTML = (JSON.stringify(obj.TotalDistance));
```

Comment: Can your provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I left an answer below, With the example of code.